# AES File Decryption

Tags: java, encryption, aes

Trying to understand following piece of code in the application that decrypting a file using AES. I am not a Java programmer. If I know the value of the variable byte a[], is it possible to decrypt the file?

```
        static byte a[] = { ..... };

        SecretKeySpec key;

        if (key == null)
        {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bos.write(a);
            bos.write(abyte1);
            key = new SecretKeySpec(bos.toByteArray(), "AES");
            bos.close();
        }
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(2, key);
        CipherInputStream cipherinputstream = new CipherInputStream(inputstream, cipher);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `a` holds the secret key except for the last byte, which seems to hide in `abyte1`. So if you know all of a, there's only 255 possible key values left and you can <strike>easily</strike> *trivially* brute-force that.

Comment: @JohnE: you're welcome. Just as a general note, it's not necessary to post "thank you" on Stackoverflow. Simply upvote if you found an answer useful (or a question, for that matter).